# Can I send message to a page using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I saw that is possible to use Graph API to send message to a user, but I didn't find nothing about send message to a page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with the API, you can only reply to a User message as Page. Sending messages from Users to Pages is not really neccessary, Users can just use the Messenger for that. Prefilling would not be allowed anyway.